# Why java scanner doesn't work when calling jar from cmd?

Tags: java, file-io, jar, cmd, java.util.scanner

I tried to read some data from my *myFile.txt* file. The code I use is like below:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"))) {
        System.out.println("Start");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println("Inside");

            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            String[] attribute = line.split(",");

            String id = attribute[0];
            String firstName = attribute[1];
            String lastName = attribute[2];

            System.out.println(id + " " + firstName+ " " + lastName);
        }
        System.out.println("The end");
    }
```

When I run this code from my IDE it works fine. But when I run the **jar** file from the cmd window it doesn't work. Only "Start" and "The end" is shown
on the cmd screen. So, **scanner.hasNextLine()** is always false.

Comment: where is the text file when you run it from the jar?

Comment: Is in the same destination as my project jar file.

Comment: Is it in the directory from which you're launching the program? i.e. if you type `ls` (or `dir`) on windows, do you see this file listed?

Comment: I think that his file is in the correct location, because there is no "FileNotFoundException".

Comment: Exactly! When I type **dir** I can see my **jar** and the file which I want to read. No, there is no exception since the two message from the code are printed on the screen and the code works fine in the IDE.

Comment: If that's the only problem you have, i'd try to use System.in for the scanner, and then redirect sysin to the file when i run the program: example: java -jar program.jar < myFile.txt

Comment: Clearly in one case you're reading an empty file.

Comment: EJP, I am new here I try to do my best to ask good question as much as possible. Please correct my question if it's necessary. No, the file is not empty. As you can see in the code there are 3 attributes (id, first name and last name). Aify, I took your advice but same effect.

Comment: If the file wasn't empty your code would print something else; if it was empty it would only print 'start' and 'end', which is exactly what is happening. QED. Have you considered the possibility, indeed the probability, that there are *two* files? One of them empty? I didn't suggest there was anything that needs correcting in your question. I don't know why you think otherwise..

Comment: There is no problem in your code. But EJP is right you should search the problem in your working environment. The code is errorless.

Comment: There is only one file and there are 10 rows, i.e. 10 contacts. So the file is not empty. The code works in Netbeans IDE. But when I try to run in cmd (java -jar projectName.jar) only "Start" and "The end" prints out. So the while loop is always false. **scanner.hasNextLine()** is always false since I can't see the "Inside" message either. emin, What do you mean by "working environment"? Because I have 2 negative points for this question and I don't know why.

Comment: Try `System.err.println(new File("myFile.txt").getAbsolutePath());` before the `try`.

Comment: @myanmar don't worry about the negative points. That's because, I think, your question is too specific and of no general interest, and also because your example is not minimal.

Comment: You are mistaken. There is an empty file. No other explanation is possible.

Comment: Giulio Franco, thank you. I don't worry I just want to be friendly and polite. I am not interested at getting points at all. As you can see I am relatively new here and have only three questions so far. I pasted your code before the try block and my path is correct. EJP, the file is not empty I can see my data.

Comment: Your code can't see your data. *Ergo* there is no data being presented to the code you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, and what's the reason for that? My data are like this in my file:

Comment: 1,xxx,yyy -> the first row, etc

Comment: Any chance that file permissions are getting in the way?

Comment: No, the code works in my IDE.

Comment: I'd say download the JavaSE sources and attach a debugger to the executing jar, then step into `hasNextLine()`

Comment: I also agree that the `Scanner` is somehow reading from some empty file (or the JavaSE implementation is broken, and doesn't throw `NoSuchFileException`). Anyway, it's clear that the `Scanner` is not reading the file you think. To confirm this, please try using the absolute file path.

Comment: When I try new **Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt")))** instead new **Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"))** everything works perfectly. Maybe it's because Scanner is not syncronized or the file is some-how encrypted and **BufferedReader** has larger buffer memoery than **Scanner**.

Answer (score 0):

From the [File javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), a File is:

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

It doesn't specifically represent an existing file, only pathnames.

The issue here is that the file you try to open does not [exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()). If your file is packed in your JAR, you can try to access it through your ClassLoader [getRessource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) method :

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myFile.txt");
```

Comment: No, my file is not packed in the JAR. See my last comment.